how use environment variables in Next js project
I would like to deploy my Next js Project so i want to save my API_KEY variable asan  environment variable then add the .env file to gitignore but the documentation of Next doesn't help me !
First, I create the .env file under the project root (Myproject/.env)
then I add my API_KEY variable :

    API_KEY=355e8d5xxxxxxxxxxxxxx


Then i used it in ListNews.jsx file under 'Myproject\src\components' :

    const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;
    useEffect(()=>{
     let url = `https://gnews.io/api/v4//top-headlines?category=${category}&lang=${language}&max=10&apikey=${API_KEY}` ;

   

But in vain, the url of the API doesn't work

How are you deploying? The env file and/or env variable need to be present where you’re running your deployed server

read the friendly manual: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables. anything you want to be accessible in a component, you must prefix with NEXT_PUBLIC_

@Samathingamajig Mind you it sort of defeats the purpose of Next.js in this case. If OP's idea is to do a fetch, they should probably get the data from a server component instead of doing it from an effect.

@moonstar-x yeah, I agree with you. I want to add information: If you're already using next.js and the build target is not static, then you have a server environment as you do with backend stuff. Do anything async stuff there and push down to the tree. Server -> data -> Client. It helps to reduce JS on the client and your page will load faster.

@Samathingamajig Thank you so much it works fine locally and in prod when I added the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC_ to my env var. :D

@moonstar-x  & Golamrabbi Azad,  thank you for your hints ^^ I used getServerSideProps to fetch initial data from the server side then I passed this initial data to ListNews compo as props.
Then I used client-side fetching in useEffect inside the  ListNews compo to update data when the user changes category or language. Regarding the performance, I don't notice a huge difference since only the initial data is provided from the server side. however, its performance is not too bad and it works fine :)

@Salsa Just an FYI, the problem isn't really performance, it's mostly related to secret management. Your request requires an API key, and by doing it from the client you're exposing your key. I'm not aware of gnews' request limits or charges, but by exposing this API key you're leaving a door open for potential bad actors to steal it and make requests on your behalf. By making the requests from the server you're making sure that the API key is never sent to the client but only the data they need.

If your request depends on parameters that the user can change (category or language), you could store them in the URL as query parameters instead of state. If you need some fancy pagination mechanics you could leverage server actions, but almost 100% of the time, for simple get queries, URL search parameters are the way to go.

@moonstar-x Thanks a lot! I understand the point now. Using query parameters is indeed a good alternative in this situation. IDK how I didn’t think of that! I was primarily focused on understanding states better. Now, I've switched to using query parameters, and I passed the data object in res.render()
